# Expendable list extends cursorTreeAdapter containing checkbox

Tags: android, expandablelistview

The problem is with saving the state of the checkbox on scroll.  When I'm scrolling down or up some unchecked items get checked because of the screen redraw.  If someone could help please.  I will provide the code of the adapter.

```
final class ExpAdapter extends CursorTreeAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        LayoutInflater mInflator;
        CursorTreeAdapter cur;

        class ViewHolder {
                    public TextView textView;
                    public CheckBox checkbox;
                }

        public ExpAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context)
        {
            super(cursor, context);
            mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor,
                boolean isLastChild) {
            //TextView tvChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

               final TextView tvChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                tvChild.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(tablename.columname...)));//child

               final CheckBox  chb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

                chb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                            //buttonView.setChecked(true);
                            buttonView.setChecked(true);
                             groupcode = mCuror2.getInt(tablename.columname));
                             levelid = mCuror2.getInt(mCuror2.getColumnIndex(tablename.columname));

                             levelidarray.add(String.valueOf(levelid));
                             groupcodearray.add(String.valueOf(groupcode));


                             String x=(String)tvChild.getText();

                             array.add(x);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // do some operations here

                        }
                        else 
                                {
                            buttonView.setChecked(false);
                            //buttonView.setChecked(false);
                            //itemChecked.set(cursor.getPosition(), false);
                            // do some operations here
                            String x = (String)tvChild.getText();

                         levelidarray.remove(String.valueOf(levelid));
                         groupcodearray.remove(String.valueOf(groupcode));
                            array.remove((String)x);

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                    }
                });


           }

       @Override
        protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,  boolean isExpanded)

           {

               TextView tvGrp = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tvGrp.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(tablename.columname)));

               TextView code = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

            }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor)
            {
               int groupId = groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(tablename.columname));

                String filter2 = " LEVEL_ID = " +groupId;
                mCuror2 = dbconnection....,filter2, null, null, null, null);

                return mCuror2;

            }


        @Override
        protected View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent)
        {

                View mView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listviewcheckbox, null);


                 final TextView tvChild = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.label);

                tvChild.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(tablename.columname)));

                CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)mView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

                chb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                            //buttonView.setChecked(true);
                            buttonView.setChecked(true);
                             groupcode = mCuror2.getInt(mCuror2.getColumnIndex(tablename.columname));
                             levelid = mCuror2.getInt(mCuror2.getColumnIndex(tablename.columname));

                             levelidarray.add(String.valueOf(levelid));
                             groupcodearray.add(String.valueOf(groupcode));


                             String x=(String)tvChild.getText();

                             array.add(x);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // do some operations here

                        }
                        else 
                                {
                            buttonView.setChecked(false);
                            //buttonView.setChecked(false);
                            //itemChecked.set(cursor.getPosition(), false);
                            // do some operations here
                            String x = (String)tvChild.getText();

                         levelidarray.remove(String.valueOf(levelid));
                         groupcodearray.remove(String.valueOf(groupcode));
                            array.remove((String)x);

                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ array, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                    }
                });

                return mView;


            }

        @Override
        protected View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent)
            {   
                View mView = mInflator.inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, null);
                TextView tvGrp = (TextView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tvGrp.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(tablename.columname)));

                TextView code = (TextView)mView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                code.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tablename.columname)));

                return mView;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not storing the checked state in your DB, you need to set an array to keep track of the checked status and then use that to set it in the adapter.  Since you need the group and child position to reference it, I think you would have to do it in the `getChildView` method rather than `bindChildView`.

Declare a class variable:

```
boolean[][] checkedStatus;
```

Populate it in your constructor:

```
public ExpAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) {      
    super(cursor, context);      
    mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);      
    checkedstatus = new boolean[cursor.getCount()][];                // initializae the first dimension of array
    for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){                         // iterate through the group cursor count
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        Cursor childCursor = ...                                     // get the childcursor for group cursor position i 
        checkedStatus[i] = new boolean[childcursor.getCount()];    // initialize the second dimension of array for group position i
        for (int j=0; j<childCursor.getCount(); j++){                // iterate through the childCursor for group position i
            checkedStatus[i][j] = false;                            // initialize the item to not checked for group position i, child position j
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your `getChildView` to set the state:

```
CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)mView.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);
if (checkedStatus[groupPosition][childPosition] == true) {
    chb.setChecked(true);
} else {
    chb.setChecked(false);
}
```

Be sure to update the array in your `onCheckedChanged` method as well.

Your other option is to store the checked status in the db, then you can just check that in your `bindView`, and write it to the DB on change and be done with it.  The penalty is, of course, having to access the DB to write/read changes each time you click the checkbox, so I usually avoid this option.

Comment: didn't work out with me ... does anyone have another solution.

Comment: My apologies, I had some really incorrect code in there.  I don;t know what I was thinking when I posted it.  I've fixed it now if you feel like trying it again.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ResourceCursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ResourceCursorTreeAdapter.html) and my solution was:

```
import android.util.SparseArray;

...

/**
 * A map of children IDs to selection state.
 */
private final SparseArray<Boolean> mSelectedChildrenMap = new SparseArray<Boolean>();

...

@Override
protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
    final int _id = cursor.getInt(...); // get ID

    Boolean selected;
    if (mSelectedChildrenMap.get(_id) == null) {
        selected = false;
        mSelectedChildrenMap.put(_id, selected);
    } else
        selected = mSelectedChildrenMap.get(_id);

    /*
     * Checkbox, you can use "view holder" approach...
     */
    CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(...);
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    mCheckBox.setChecked(selected);
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mSelectedChildrenMap.put(_id, isChecked);
        }// onCheckedChanged()
    });

    ...
}// bindChildView()

...

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged(boolean releaseCursors) {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged(releaseCursors);
    /*
     * Only clears the map if releaseCursors == true.
     */
    if (releaseCursors)
        synchronized (mSelectedChildrenMap) {
            mSelectedChildrenMap.clear();
        }
}// notifyDataSetChanged()

@Override
public void notifyDataSetInvalidated() {
    super.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    /*
     * Clears the map.
     */
    synchronized (mSelectedChildrenMap) {
        mSelectedChildrenMap.clear();
    }
}// notifyDataSetInvalidated()
```

Hope it helps  :-)